# Insert into with variables php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im having some trouble getting my SQL query to 'insert into' my database, is it allowed to use variables as table name, field name, and values?

Here my code:

```
$nameOfDBFromA = "vagtplanA" . $_GET["from"];

$flytnedToQ1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM $nameOfDBToA WHERE ansatId='$_GET[ansatId]' ORDER BY id DESC");
$flytnedToQ1->execute();
$flytnedTo1 = $flytnedToQ1->fetch();

$nameOfFieldToA1 = "a" . $_GET["to"] . "1";
$nameOfFieldToA2 = "a" . $_GET["to"] . "2";
$nameOfFieldToA3 = "a" . $_GET["to"] . "3";
$nameOfFieldToA4 = "a" . $_GET["to"] . "4";
$nameOfFieldToA5 = "a" . $_GET["to"] . "5";
$nameOfFieldToA6 = "a" . $_GET["to"] . "6";
$nameOfFieldToA7 = "a" . $_GET["to"] . "7";

$redigeringsTidspunkt = date("j M Y");

$flytnedTA = $con->prepare(
         "INSERT INTO $nameOfDBFromA 
                (ansatId, edit, $nameOfFieldToA1, $nameOfFieldToA2, 
                 $nameOfFieldToA3, $nameOfFieldToA4, $nameOfFieldToA5, 
                 $nameOfFieldToA6, $nameOfFieldToA7) 
          VALUES($_GET[ansatId], $redigeringsTidspunkt, 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1], $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA2], 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3], $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA4], 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA5], $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA6], 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA7]) ") 
          or die(mysql_error());
$flytnedTA->execute();
```

**SOLVED! I just put my arrays into it own variable**

```
$intoVarToA1 = $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1];
$intoVarToA2 = $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA2];
$intoVarToA3 = $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3];
$intoVarToA4 = $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA4];
$intoVarToA5 = $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA5];
$intoVarToA6 = $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA6];
$intoVarToA7 = $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA7];
```

Comment: Im suspecting it might be the arrays in the values section?

Comment: you haven't quoted ANY of your values, so almost 99.999999% certain you've got an [sql injection](http://bobby-tables.com) problem. And since `mysql_*()` has no prepared statements, you're probably ALSO mixing mysql apis, which is also not going to work. `mysql_error()` can only report on errors caused by the mysql_*() functions, **NOT** mysqli or pdo.

Comment: Sorry that i didn't post more of my code in proper context. The quotes in values doesnt solve the problem, ive tried that a thousand times, with and without. This should work, there's something with the syntax i dont know about. All my variables have what they need to contain. have checked them so many times.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Since you're using `mysqli`, you should use `$flytnedTA->bind_param()` rather than substituting variables into the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of your mistakes is when you want to access a value in an array inside of a string, you can't do:

```
"$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1]"
```

You have to do it like this:

```
"{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1]}" // use curly brackets
```

Comment: Just tried that too, the same result. I'm sure you're right about the syntax, but there must be something else going on.

Comment: Could u echo the output of input to the prepare() function. That should help us to identify the issue. I.e $test ="INSERT INTO $nameOfDBFromA (ansatId, edit, $nameOfFieldToA1, $nameOfFieldToA2, $nameOfFieldToA3, $nameOfFieldToA4, $nameOfFieldToA5, $nameOfFieldToA6, $nameOfFieldToA7) VALUES ('$_GET[ansatId]', '$redigeringsTidspunkt', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA2]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA4]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA5]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA6]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA7]}') "; echo $test;

Comment: here: INSERT INTO vagtplanA1 (ansatId, edit, a21, a22, a23, a24, a25, a26, a27) VALUES ('5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '')

Comment: $redigeringsTidspunkt seem to have a problem too? that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't substitute variables into the query, you should use `bind_param()` to provide parameter values for the prepared query.

```
$flytnedTA = $con->prepare(
         "INSERT INTO $nameOfDBFromA 
                (ansatId, edit, $nameOfFieldToA1, $nameOfFieldToA2, 
                 $nameOfFieldToA3, $nameOfFieldToA4, $nameOfFieldToA5, 
                 $nameOfFieldToA6, $nameOfFieldToA7) 
          VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ") 
          or die(mysqli_error($con));
$flytnedTA->bind_param("sssssssss", $_GET[ansatId], $redigeringsTidspunkt, 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1], $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA2], 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3], $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA4], 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA5], $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA6], 
                 $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA7]);
$flytnedTA->execute();
```

You also need to call `mysqli_error($con)`, not `mysql_error()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have variables like that, you can insert data into db like below in php.

```
 $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstname']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastname']);
    $email_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO persons (first_name, last_name, email_address) VALUES    ('$first_name', '$last_name', '$email_address')";
```

Comment: That method is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared statement and parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thank you Riggs ! I looked Prepared Statements. Generally I code queries in yii2 Active Record.

Answer (score 0):

Is not a good practice put _GET or _POST variables directly on query, use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to clear the value in variable.

The array values are not parsed directly in strings, you must enclose the expression in `{}`:

For this: `" $flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3] "` replace with: `"'{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3]}'"` , the result value also need to enclosed by `''` singlequoes for sql string value.

```
$flytnedTA = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO $nameOfDBFromA (ansatId, edit, $nameOfFieldToA1, $nameOfFieldToA2, $nameOfFieldToA3,
    $nameOfFieldToA4, $nameOfFieldToA5, $nameOfFieldToA6, $nameOfFieldToA7) 
    VALUES({$_GET['ansatId']}, '$redigeringsTidspunkt', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA2]}', 
    '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA4]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA5]}', 
    '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA6]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA7]}') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Just tried it no luck.. Maybe its because i have variables as field names, ansatId, edit, $nameOfFieldToA1, $nameOfFieldToA2, $nameOfFieldToA3,
    $nameOfFieldToA4, $nameOfFieldToA5, $nameOfFieldToA6, $nameOfFieldToA7?

Comment: Can you show me the result of this string? `echo "INSERT INTO $nameOfDBFromA (ansatId, edit, $nameOfFieldToA1, $nameOfFieldToA2, $nameOfFieldToA3,
    $nameOfFieldToA4, $nameOfFieldToA5, $nameOfFieldToA6, $nameOfFieldToA7) 
    VALUES({$_GET['ansatId']}, '$redigeringsTidspunkt', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA1]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA2]}', 
    '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA3]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA4]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA5]}', 
    '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA6]}', '{$flytnedTo1[$nameOfFieldToA7]}') "`